# Field not adding to a Mongodb document

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I am trying to add a new field to a document in a collection in a mongodb database using python. However, I am unable to add the field. Here is my code: -

```
mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017) #Connecting to mongo
mng_db = mng_client['Test'] #Database
collection_name = mng_db["Practice"] #Collection
mng_db.collection_name.update_one({}, {"$set":{'Name' : 'Ron'}}, False, True)
```

If I set the upsert as true, then a new collection is created in the database. However, if the upsert is false then nothing happens to the existing document. Could someone help me understand what mistake I am making in my code? I apologise in advance if my problem is trivial since I have never using mongodb before.

Edit: Fixed the code a bit

Comment: You seem to be using the deprecated `update` function instead of the newer `update_many` function.

Comment: My bad, I was debugging and didn't change "update" back. I actually used update_one which gives me the same results.